# python3 ModuleNotFoundError with my own modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

[image: structure]

I have this project structure. I want to import my Restaurant class from `models/restaurant.py` in `data/datadownload.py` like this:

```
from models.restaurant import Restaurant
```

And I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`.

**Note:** both modules (data and models) are int the root folder of the project. And I also tried to make the root folder a module by adding `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: what about `from ..models.restaurant import Restaurant`

Comment: What/where is the main script (start script)?

Comment: @BijayRegmi You mean `sys.path.append()`.

Comment: @BijayRegmi Is sys.path.append() a relevant solution ? Is it portable ?

Comment: @MichaelButscher the main script is in the root folder

Comment: @BijayRegmi from ..models.restaurant import Restaurant
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah sorry, i meant `sys.path.append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: I solved the problem by exporting `PYTHONPATH`environment variable:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
```

**Note**: The solution works on Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import something within the same directory that is in a different directory try using:

```
from ..models.restaurant import Restaurant
```

to make the code more portable

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
Even when I add an `__init__.py` file to the parent directory (which is the root folder).